# How to get number of unique observations using tbl_summary

Tags: r, gtsummary

In the data below, I have 7 patients who have undergone surgeries for 9 conditions, two of the patients have undergone surgery on the same day for two different reasons. When I try to summarise this data using tbl_summary function, it shows total number of observations as 9. I want to add total number of patients, which is n = 7.I am not understanding how do I add that information in the table. Could you guys please help me with this?

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

participant.index = c(1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7)
repeat.instance = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
indication.surgery = c("ibs","infection", "infection", "renalstones", "ibs", "infection",
                 "infection", "ibs","tumour")
date.surgery =c("2019-01-10", "2019-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2017-09-10",
          "2000-09-09","2015-01-10","2015-01-10","2006-09-09")
mydata = data.table(participant.index,repeat.instance,indication.surgery,date.surgery)

mydata%>%
  select(indication.surgery)%>%
  tbl_summary
label = list(indication.surgery ~
"Indication for Surgery"),
statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n}  ({p}%)"),
missing_text = "(Missing Observations)",
percent = c("cell")
) %>%
  modify_table_styling(spanning_header =  "Indications for Surgery") %>%
  modify_caption("**Table 1. Indication for Surgery**") %>%
  modify_footnote(all_stat_cols() ~ "Number of observations, Frequency (%)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! If you add an indicator for the first participant index and include that new variable in the summary table, you can include it in the summary. Example Below!

```r
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

participant.index <- c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7)
repeat.instance <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
indication.surgery <- c(
  "ibs", "infection", "infection", "renalstones", "ibs", "infection",
  "infection", "ibs", "tumour"
)
date.surgery <- c(
  "2019-01-10", "2019-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2017-09-10",
  "2000-09-09", "2015-01-10", "2015-01-10", "2006-09-09"
)
mydata <- 
  data.table(participant.index, repeat.instance, 
             indication.surgery, date.surgery) %>%
  group_by(participant.index) %>%
  mutate(first.participant.index = row_number() == 1L, 
         .before = 1L) %>%
  ungroup()

mydata %>%
  select(first.participant.index, indication.surgery) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    label = 
      list(first.participant.index ~ "No. Unique Participants", 
           indication.surgery ~ "Indication for Surgery"),
    statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)",
                     first.participant.index ~ "{n}"),
    missing_text = "(Missing Observations)",
    percent = c("cell")
  ) %>%
  modify_table_styling(spanning_header = "Indications for Surgery") %>%
  modify_caption("**Table 1. Indication for Surgery**") %>%
  modify_footnote(all_stat_cols() ~ "Number of observations, Frequency (%)")
```

[image]

Comment: Build a separate tbl_summary with the proper denominator, and use tbl_merge() to combine the tables.